# Py2exe doesnt work

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, executable, desktop-application, py2exe

When I run py2exe the program builds the application, but when I run the executable in the dist folder the application gives an error and closes immediately, I don't even have the time to read it. Does anybody know what I do wrong?

Edit: the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "volex7.py", line 5, in <module>
    File "OpenGL\GL\__init__.pyc", line3, in <module>
    File "OpenGL\error.pyc", line 12, in <module>
    File "OpenGL\platform\__init__.pyc", line 35, in <module>
    File "OpenGL\platform\__init__.pyc", line 29 in _load
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: To see the error message, you need to launch the application from a command window.  Open the Start Menu, type `cmd` and press `ENTER`.